# CollectionMAx My SQL5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm having issue with my payment processing with my collection software.

I'm not familiar with MYSQL5.5 and I keep getting an error about my column not match row value.

The exact error message is as follows:

There was an error updating the database: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I understand that maybe a trigger is running. But I do not understand how to fix this. Can someone provide a little assistance. Maybe step by step. 
Image of the error mesg is below:

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to some problems

Maybe its because of the trigger.
 The trigger  you have created may needs to be changed or removed.

You can find more about your problem here
http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/mysql/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-in-mysql

Hope this helps you out ..:)